# Memcached doesn't work correctly for all the websites

Tags: php, wordpress, memcached

I've got a weird issue lately and I am not sure what causes it. I've got a dedicated box with a few websites on it and it seems like memcache only works on half of them.

2 wordpress websites (both got W3 Total Cache with same settings) and one of them is stuck while the other one works fine. If I manually clear cache from W3 it will work until the next post.

At first I thought it was plugin's fault but then I've noticed similar issues on some of my other sites. For example, when I try to update a php file it will show me the file I uploaded unless the file size is different.

Another occasion was DIR which would point out to the old folder name (the one used when it was uploaded) unless I edit all the files in that folder that had DIR in them.

Any ideas/suggestions?

PS: All these things started happening after I installed php curl on my server.

Comment: to start off, the sites that you think that doesn't have memcached working working try to look at the log file. issue > tailf /var/log/memcached.log if you're on linux or if you're on windows, see if there's anything in that file any erros

Comment: @unixmiah the log file is empty

Comment: installing php-curl should not have anything to do with memcached not working. will you be able to re-install memcached if anything were to to corrupt.

Comment: I did flush memcache now and it temporarilly fixed the WP problem (it is not updating once again) but not the DIR one. Can't really understand what is going on.